# The stream was unable to connect due to a network error. Make sure your connection isn't blocked by a firewall - Tokbox error

Tags: ionic2, angular2-services, opentok, tokbox

The application that we have is developed in Angular 2.

To make use of tokbox we have 2 parts:

1. mobile part developed in Angular 2 (Ionic 2) that is the one that makes the call.
2. Web part developed in .Net what is the one that answers the call.

When we execute both projects on the web the call is executed correctly, but, when we run the part of Angular on a mobile device(iPhone), the error: "**The stream was unable to connect due to a network error. Make sure your connection isn't blocked by a firewall**" is presented, on the device and on the web, only the camera corresponding to that participant is opened ( To the web that is the one that answers the call).

Comment: How are you adding WebRTC support to iOS? Are you using a cordova plugin? Safari on iOS does not support WebRTC, at least not until iOS 11 and even at that point it will not be available in the Web View that is used by Cordova.

Comment: I'm using this plugin [cordova-plugin-opentok](https://github.com/taracque/cordova-plugin-opentok/)
The project is in Angular 2 so it does not run in Safari but in the same application. The web part runs correctly in Google Chrome.

I've tried it on Android and it does not work either

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: @huanfeng no, I changed the technology